# How to add auto complete address to dynamically added input fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I want that user to see an alert whenever he doesn't enter proper Google address (or select from suggestion box) on dynamically added text areas. How can I perform that?

I have tried the following code.
I want that when I add new `divs` at runtime the auto-complete method should apply on that input field and when the user clicks submit button without selecting any suggested address it should display an alert.
Please help me where am I wrong in my code?

```js
function updateNames() {

var rows = $(".clonedInput");
var index = 0;

rows.each(function () {
    var inputFields = $(this).find("input");
    inputFields.each(function () {
        var currentName = $(this).attr("name");
        
        $(this).removeClass("hasDatepicker");
        $(this).removeClass("hasTimepicker");
        
        $(this).attr("name", currentName.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, '[' + index + ']'));
        
    });
    
    var textareaFields = $(this).find("textarea");
    textareaFields.each(function () {
        
        var currName = $(this).attr("name");
        $(this).attr("name", currName.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, '[' + index + ']'));
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(currName);
        var a = places.getPlace();
        if (a == null) {
            alert('Please Select a valid location');
            
        }
        else { }
        var currId = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).attr("id", currId.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, '[' + index + ']'));
        
    });
    
    var numberSpan = $(this).find("span.taskNumber");
    numberSpan.html(index + 1);
    
    index++;
    
});
}
```